# How to multiply and divide in from multiple querys?

Tags: mysql, sql

So right now i have 3 queries:

Lets call this query X

```
SELECT count(*) as totalDrink from 
Drink D join History H where H.drinkName = D.name AND type = 'vodka' and userID = 'sai'
```

query Y

```
SELECT count(*) as totalDrink from 
Drink D join Favorite F where F.drinkName = D.name AND type = 'vodka' and userID = 'sai'
```

query Z

```
SELECT SUM(totalDrinks) as total FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) totalDrinks FROM History
WHERE userID = 'sai'
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Favorite
WHERE userID = 'sai'
) as totalDrink
```

Basically I want to do in mySQL and output that:

(X + Y(0.666))/Z

Comment: Just to note: 
Querys X, Y, and Z will each output only 1 tuple so I think there should be a way to do scalar multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most directly:

```
SELECT (
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   Drink D JOIN History  H ON H.drinkName = D.name
    WHERE  type = 'vodka' AND userID = 'sai'
  ) + (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   Drink D JOIN Favorite F ON F.drinkName = D.name
    WHERE  type = 'vodka' AND userID = 'sai' 
  )
) / (
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM History  WHERE userID = 'sai'
  ) + (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Favorite WHERE userID = 'sai'
  )
)
```

Comment: Yeah, I would like to say there is a more elegant solution with prepared statements or joins, but the way OP's question is worded and without example it's hard to find a way to avoid using subqueries.